# Is it Okay to Appear Constantly as Offline but Reply Back Instantly?

Tags: communication, group-dynamics

On apps such as Mattermost, there are the following online status symbols:

[image]

To be honest, I don't (i) like and (ii) want people to know on which times I'm online, and on which times I'm not. I feel like this is a huge intrusion into my privacy. For example, if I want to check sth at 11pm, then I want to freely do this, without people knowing.

Is it okay/accepted to appear constantly as offline during weekdays, but still reply back "instantly" when sb writes to me privately, when I chat with the professor (my boss) or with our students?

I know that appearing online at some points might make life easier for some people (particularly for students), and also the prof. might be wondering what is going on. All people from our group regularly appear as "online" or "away" during usual office hours, but I just don't seem to be able to cope with these things (though to be fair, via email, nobody knows whether I'm online or away or off either).

Comment: This is a general workplace/relation question, not specific to academia.

Comment: You are overthinking this. A person who constantly appears offline might indeed be offline, but still receive notifications.

Answer (score 5):

**It's okay to work as you please.**

I personally consider communication applications (email, messaging, chat, ...) as a distraction and I prefer to leave them closed, which goes further than *appear[ing] constantly as offline...but still reply[ing] "instantly."*

You are free to define your own communication strategy. (Assuming you aren't mandated otherwise.) Of course, your strategy impacts others and some adjustments may be necessary.